# How to get only first element in list contained in string?

Tags: python, list, json5

I've got a long string. This string contains a list, like such example

```
'[{"ex1": 0, "ex2":1}, {"ex3": 2, "ex4":3}]'
```

I can use `json5.loads` and then get the first element by using `[0]` on the list, but `json5.loads` takes a long time for longer strings. Is there a way to get just the first element without loading the entire list? (in this example it would be `{"ex1": 0, "ex2":1}`. Splitting by commas doesn't work for me since there are commas contained in dictionaries in the list. Thanks.

Comment: Use the `json` module from the standard library instead?

Comment: Is the `json` module more efficient than `json5`?

Comment: From the PyPi page for the package `This is an early release. It has been reasonably well-tested, but it is SLOW. It can be 1000-6000x slower than the C-optimized JSON module, and is 200x slower (or more) than the pure Python JSON module` https://pypi.org/project/json5/

Comment: I use the `json5` module because it allows single-quoted strings, and will allow more flexibility. Any other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your string work with `ast.literal_eval()`? If it does, you could do

```
obj = ast.literal_eval(s)
# obj[0] gives the first dict
```

If not, you could loop through the string character-by-character and yield any substring when the number of open-brackets are equal to the number of close-brackets.

```
def get_top_level_dict_str(s):
  open_br = 0
  close_br = 0
  open_index = 0
  for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c == '{':
        if open_br == 0: open_index = i 
        open_br += 1
    elif c == '}':
        close_br += 1
        if open_br > 0 and open_br == close_br:
            yield s[open_index:i+1]
            open_br = close_br = 0
```

If you want to parse the resulting substrings to objects, you could use `json5` like you already do, which is probably faster on the smaller string, or use `ast.literal_eval()`

```
x = get_top_level_dict_str(s)
# next(x) gives the substring
# then use json5 or ast.literal_eval()
```

Comment: Please excuse any typos, I added this answer on my phone

Answer (score 0):

If it'll definitely be that format, you can just search for the beginning and ending brackets.

```
mystr = '[{"ex1": 0, "ex2":1}, {"ex3": 2, "ex4":3}]'
first = mystr.index("{")
last = mystr.index("}")
extracted = mystr[first:last+1]
print(extracted)
```

this prints
'{"ex1": 0, "ex2":1}'

For a more complicated string:

```
mystr = '[{"ex1": {"ex1.33": -1, "ex1.66": -2}, "ex2":1}, {"ex3": 2, "ex4":3}]'
n_open = 0
n_close = 0
first = mystr.index("{")
for ii in range(len(mystr)):
    if mystr[ii] == "{":
        n_open += 1
    elif mystr[ii] == "}":
        n_close += 1
    if n_open > 0 and n_open == n_close:
        break
extracted = mystr[first:ii+1]
```

Comment: That was just an example, my actual string is much more complicated and has many nested brackets. Any other ways? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Without more specifics, it's hard to offer something more concrete. You can do while loop as you step through the string, but that'll probably be pretty slow. Count the number of open brackets and close brackets, and exit out when the number of close brackets equals the number of open (and the number is >0)

Comment: I'll try that, thanks for the idea.

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example for a more generic finder